# RichTextBox opening in another form while mousehovering

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application with various forms, i have added 4 RichTextBox in a form, and in another form i am using RadioButton, i want the RIchTextBix to be visible in second form when i hover over the RadioBUttons. also it should always be visible in first form.

FOrm2 Code

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form

    Private dashboard As Dashboard
    Private mapView As MapView

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        dashboard = New Dashboard()
        mapView = New MapView(dashboard)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadFormInPanel(formToShow As Form)
        formToShow.TopLevel = False
        formToShow.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        formToShow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        Panel2.Controls.Add(formToShow)
        formToShow.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BunifuThinButton21_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton21.Click
        LoadFormInPanel(New Dashboard())
        'Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        'Dashboard.TopLevel = False
        'Panel2.Controls.Add(Dashboard)
        'Dashboard.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel2.Paint

    End Sub

    Private Sub BunifuThinButton22_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton22.Click
        LoadFormInPanel(New MapView())
        'Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        'MapView.TopLevel = False
        'Panel2.Controls.Add(MapView)
        'MapView.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BunifuThinButton23_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton23.Click
        LoadFormInPanel(New Route())
        'Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        'Route.TopLevel = False
        'Panel2.Controls.Add(Route)
        'Route.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BunifuThinButton24_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton24.Click
        LoadFormInPanel(New AboutUs())
        'Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        'AboutUs.TopLevel = False
        'Panel2.Controls.Add(AboutUs)
        'AboutUs.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BunifuThinButton25_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuThinButton25.Click
        LoadFormInPanel(New ContactUs())
        'Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        'ContactUs.TopLevel = False
        'Panel2.Controls.Add(ContactUs)
        'ContactUs.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Dashboard code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Dashboard
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowRichTextBox(ByVal richTextBoxNumber As Integer)

        ' Show the selected RichTextBox
        Select Case richTextBoxNumber
            Case 1
                RichTextBox1.Visible = True
            Case 2
                RichTextBox2.Visible = True
            Case 3
                RichTextBox3.Visible = True
            Case 4
                RichTextBox4.Visible = True
        End Select
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property RichTextBox1Control As RichTextBox
        Get
            Return RichTextBox1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RichTextBox2Control As RichTextBox
        Get
            Return RichTextBox2
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RichTextBox3Control As RichTextBox
        Get
            Return RichTextBox3
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RichTextBox4Control As RichTextBox
        Get
            Return RichTextBox4
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

MapView code

```
Imports System.Windows.Form
Public Class MapView
    Inherits Form

    Private dashboard As Dashboard
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(dashboardForm As Dashboard)
        InitializeComponent()
        dashboard = dashboardForm
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.MouseHover
        dashboard?.ShowRichTextBox(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.MouseHover
        dashboard?.ShowRichTextBox(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.MouseHover
        dashboard?.ShowRichTextBox(3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.MouseHover
        dashboard?.ShowRichTextBox(4)
    End Sub

    ' Similarly, handle other radio buttons' MouseHover events

    ' ... other code ...
End Class
```

Comment: So you want a Richtext tool tip?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe to convert to html and this to display it in a tooltip https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer.

Comment: @CoolCoder123 This is WinForms, nothing to do with HTML. Also not related to tooltips

Comment: I thought he wanted a tool tip since he wants it to only show on hover, converting the RTF to html would be a way to accomplish that not?

Comment: @CoolCoder123 Again, this is WinForms (desktop application), what has HTML to do with it? The OP is not asking for a tooltip either, something much simpler

Comment: I guess if it's not a tool tip you could create a clone of the Richtext and add it to the form on hover and then handle mouseleave event and remove it.